# Testing rails controller with rspec within a plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm writing a Rails plugin and I'd like to be able to test a controller within the plugin:

```
describe ReportsController, :type => :controller do

  it "shows paginated reports if the user is authorized" do
    get 'index'
    response.should render_template("index")
  end

end
```

unfortunately this results in the following error:

```
NoMethodError in 'ReportsController index action shows paginated reports if the user is authorized'
undefined method `get' for #<Spec::Example::ExampleGroup::Subclass_1::Subclass_1:0x7f7155e042a0>
```

Rails env in plugin's spec_helper.rb is loaded:

```
ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] ||= File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../../..'
require File.expand_path(File.join(ENV['RAILS_ROOT'], 'config/environment.rb'))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding:

```
require File.expand_path(File.join(ENV['RAILS_ROOT'], 'spec/spec_helper.rb'))
```

to plugin_dir/spec/spec_helper.rb